# Cost of iterating over cells in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios

Inside each `UITableViewCell` of my `UITableView`, I have a `UIScrollView`. The scroll view is setup so that when the user swipes right a menu will appear. This is similar to the behavior of the cells in the iPhone Twitter app. When a user swipes upon another cell I iterate over all visible cells to tell the `UIScrollView` to scroll back to the cell content (i.e. its initial position). The iteration is done in the `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` method with the following code:

```
   - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

        if( [scrollView tag] == 90 ) {

            NSLog(@"Dragging a scroll view inside a cell!");

            for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {

                [(UICellContentScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:90] scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, [cell frame].size.height) animated:YES];

            }

        }

    }
```

In the method `viewDidDisappear` I iterate again over all cells to reset various things like so:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];


    for( NSUInteger section = 0; section < [[self tableView] numberOfSections]; section++ ) {

        for( NSUInteger row = 0; row < [[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++ ) {

            UITableViewCell *cell = [[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
             // resetting cell here

        }

    }

}
```

My question is if I am (a) going about this the right way and (b) does anyone have any recommendations on a better solution considering the table view may be storing up 50 (no more than 100) items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `NSNotification` documentation. You could register all of your `UITableViewCell` objects to receive a notification you could call something like "cellWasSwiped" or "needToResetCells" or whatever. Then whenever you want to reset the cells you just post the notification. All of your `UITableViewCell` objects that are registered to receive it will get the notification and can then call whatever method you need.